# does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: Unrecognized selector (NSTimer)

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am using an `NSTimer` in my Swift app in the following way:

```
func playEvent(eventIndex : Int){
    if (eventIndex < 2){
        let currEvent = self.eventArray[eventIndex]
        currEvent?.startEvent()
        let nextIndex = eventIndex + 1
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval((currEvent?.duration)!, target: self, selector: "playEvent(nextIndex)", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else if (eventIndex==2){
        self.eventArray[eventIndex]?.startEvent()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "finishSentence", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else{
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

I think the problem may be either that I am not property calling the selector method with a  parameter. If that is impossible, how could I work around this?
There is being called on the first `NSTimer` instance. Here is the full Swift class for reference: https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/79941733b82f5fe58282

Comment: You can't pass nextIndex into selector directly, "playEvent(nextIndex)" which is a string

Comment: how can I do it without making nextIndex some kind of global variable, which seems blasphemous!

Comment: but if its the only way...

Comment: You can also pass nextIndex via userInfo of NSTimer, please take my answer for references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass nextIndex into a selector directly. One option for NSTimer could be to pass values via userInfo, for example:

```
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, 
        selector: "mySelector:", 
        userInfo: NSNumber(integer: 999), 
        repeats: true)

    func mySelector(timer: NSTimer){
            print(timer.userInfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A selector is represented by the method name

```
func playEvent()

selector: "playEvent"
```

If the method has one parameter, a colon is added

```
func playEvent(eventIndex : Int)

selector: "playEvent:"
```

If the method has multiple parameters, all parameter names are concatenated separated by colons

```
func playEvent(eventIndex : Int, flag: Bool)

selector: "playEvent:flag:"
```

---

Using `NSTimer` the direct parameter is designated to hold the timer instance.

```
func playEvent(timer : NSTimer)
```

You have to pass further parameters via the `userInfo` object of the timer.